# libsqlite3.dylib security error

Tags: macos, sqlite, executable

I am having trouble with the libsqlite3.dylib library; when I try to run, I am receiving the following error message:

```
 dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  Reason: Incompatible library version: Security requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libsqlite3.dylib provides version 1.0.0
Trace/BPT trap
```

Everything I've been able to find says to copy libsqlite3.dylib to your app folder, but they say to take the one **from** /usr/lib, and that's the one that is causing the error.

I've tried updating using ports:

```
$ sudo port clean sqlite3
Password:
--->  Cleaning sqlite3
$ sudo port install sqlite3
--->  Computing dependencies for sqlite3
--->  Cleaning sqlite3
$
```

and I went so far as to download sqlite3, and I ran the **make** and **make install**.

I am still getting this error.

Does anyone know how to fix this error??

Comment: I have DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH set, and I've done "export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=true" which shows that /usr/lib is causing the problem